# Draw arrow with pan using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, transform, skitch

What I've got working:

I have been trying to add an arrow to an app, but am having the a most difficult time getting it to do what it needs to do. The arrow needs to be drawn from a start point as represented by a finger touch and increase in size while the user drags a finger across the screen. The arrow then must stop drawing one the finger is lifted.

What I'm having trouble with:

The arrow must be able to rotate around both the start point and the end point when the user touches a point a either end of the arrow and drags a finger in a direction. While rotating, the arrow must be able to increase and decrease it's size.

I am able to get the arrow to somewhat rotate around the start point, but with issues. Rotating around the end point causes a "fish tailing" effect. I'm pretty sure the way I'm doing it is completely wrong, but I don't know of any other way. This is why asking the community to steer me in the right direction.

```
@implementation ViewController {
ArrowView *_selectedArrowView;
UIColor *_selectedColor;
CGFloat _selectedWeight;
CGFloat _initalAngle;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _selectedColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    _selectedWeight = 3;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panHandler:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];

    _selectedArrowView = [[ArrowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 300, 150, 25) withColor:_selectedColor withWeight:_selectedWeight withStartPoint:CGPointMake(300, 300) withEndPoint:CGPointMake(450, 300)];
    _selectedArrowView.delegate = self;
    _selectedArrowView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    _selectedArrowView.layer.position = CGPointMake(150,300);
    [self.view addSubview:_selectedArrowView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_selectedArrowView];
}

- (void) panHandler: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:sender.view];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _initalAngle = atan2(touchPoint.y, touchPoint.x);
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGFloat currentAngle = atan2(touchPoint.y, touchPoint.x);
        CGFloat angle = _initalAngle - currentAngle;
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * -1);
        _selectedArrowView.transform = transform;
    }
}

@end
```

[Link to code on GitHub](https://github.com/SolaricSoftware/RotationTest)

Comment: "an arrow with the same functionality as the arrow in the Skitch app" Can you describe what that means?

Comment: The arrow needs to do the following:

1. Draw on screen with finger motion. (I got this one working.)
2. Pan in a 360 degree circle with either the start point or the end point of the arrow being the pivot point. (The one I'm having trouble getting right.)

I gave Skitch as an example as it is much easier to see than describe.

Comment: So you are misusing the word "pan"? You really just mean rotate?

Comment: Yes, rotate an arrow in a 360 degree circle around a central point from which the arrow originated while being able to increase the size from and to the point of origin.

Comment: I'm sorry, you keep changing the "spec". This is the first time you've mentioned "while being able to increase the size". This makes it very unclear what the question is, and makes it impossible to help. Please stop and give some thought to exactly what it is that you want. Then edit your question to describe clearly the problem you're having, showing the code you've got so far.

Comment: I've made it hopefully clearer.

Comment: "The arrow must be able to rotate around both the start point and the end point" How can the arrow rotate around _two_ points? I think what you mean is: if the user starts at one end, the arrow must rotate around, and grow from, the other end. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Kind of. Here is a use case. The user starts at the left middle of the screen and moves his finger right at a 90 degree angle. The arrow should grow from the left middle to the point at which his finger is at. If the user then moves his finger to a 45 degree angle, the arrow should pivot around start point to match the movement of his finger. Once the finger is lifted, the arrow remains at that positions. If the user the selects one end and moves his finger around the screen, the arrow should pivot around the opposite end the user has touched as well as resize the length of the arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that the heart of the problem you're actually having is this (from your comment):

> If the user the selects one end and moves his finger around the screen, the arrow should pivot around the opposite end the user has touched as well as resize the length of the arrow.

Let's assume the arrow is actually a view that draws the arrow within itself. So this is really about stretching and rotating the view. Let's just tackle the rotation part for now. Clearly this is going to be accomplished by applying a rotation transform that "follows" the user's touch. The thing to understand here is that a view is actually a layer, and a layer rotates around its `anchorPoint`.

So, when the user first touches the view, you must look to see where the touch is within the view, and decide which end this is. You must then move the `anchorPoint` to the *other* end, so that when we subsequently rotate, you'll be rotating around the other end. However, changing the `anchorPoint` will cause the view to jump unless you also change the layer's `position` to compensate, so you'll do that as well.

We have now safely shifted the `anchorPoint` to the end opposite the user's finger. Now we just need to rotate around it to follow the user's finger as the gesture continues. You'll do this by translating the touch coordinates from Cartesian into Polar coordinates, thus giving the angle to be applied. At the start of the gesture, save the *initial* angle; as the gesture continues, subtract that from the current angle and set the `transform` to a rotation transform using that resulting difference angle.

It often helps to simplify the problem. In this example, I'm not following a finger - just animating. As you can see, I can readily rotate around one end of the arrow, then the other end, then the first end again, and so on. This shows, in action, the effect of shifting both the `anchorPoint` and the `position` before applying a rotation transform. I suggest you work on this simple aspect of the problem before worrying about following the user's finger.

[image]

Comment: I've implemented the above, but it will only rotate about 30 degrees at most. I'm sure I'm just some small something. I've edit the question to include the code that was implemented. I'm keeping it simple and only dealing with trying to get one point to rotate.

Comment: You have to calculate the angle (polar coordinates) _with respect to the anchor point_ that you want to rotate around. - It might help you to look at some code that actually works: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_custom_controls Okay, I'm rotating around the center of the view, not the far end of the view, but the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you sir. I much appreciate the help. I'm now able to rotate the arrow around both ends. Now, when I got to reposition the arrow from a 45 degree angle to a 135 degree angle, opposite end jumps to the Y position. This makes sense because because of the anchor point change. Now I'm off to find a solution of  this problem. I also ordered you book "Programming iOS 8" because I clearly need it. Thanks again.

Comment: "when I got to reposition the arrow from a 45 degree angle to a 135 degree angle, opposite end jumps to the Y position. This makes sense because because of the anchor point change" I thought this would be taken care of when I said you needed to change the `position` when you changed the `anchorPoint`, but clearly not - it sounds like the rotation transform must also be changed to compensate, which I didn't think of. Sorry about that!

Comment: Do you know of a good example of how it should be changed? I tried playing around with CGAffineTransformTranslate, but I'm not if that should event be used. I also tried transforming the arrow layer itself, but that didn't work out either.

Comment: I think I was right the first time and wrong in my later comment. You don't need to change the rotation transform. I've put up a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/G73YdRSa8GQ) showing how easy it is to rotate first from one end, then from the other. I don't know why the YouTube quality is so sucky but you can see clearly that I'm doing what you're describing. I'm not following a finger - just animating. I suggest you work on this simple aspect of the problem before worrying about following the user's finger.

Comment: Would you mind posting the a code snippet when have moment?

Comment: Yes, I would. I'm not going to write your code for you. What part of the spec remains problematic? I believe I've described thoroughly what a possible approach would be.

Comment: I'm not asking you to right the code for me. I'm just asking for an code example. Just a point in the right direction. If you don't want to, then it's cool. I appreciate your help that you've given. I'm having trouble understanding the transforms and how you applied them to the problem.

Comment: But an example _of what_? I've asked you, and you have not answered, what part it is that you're having trouble with. As I already explained, I didn't do _anything_ with transforms in my code, except to set the transform in order to perform each animated rotation. That is why I'm suggesting that you try to reproduce what I'm doing, so that you understand what's needed here.

Comment: I have reproduced what you did, but I can't figure out how you calculated the layer position. That what was hoping to get from the example code.

Comment: Assume the arrow is vertical within an unrotated layer/view. The new `anchorPoint` is then obviously either `0.5,0` or `0.5,1`. Take whichever one it is. Using the layer's bounds size, translate to an actual point value. Convert that point into superlayer coordinates. That's the new `position`.